# How can i get multiple values from one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am building a chat application where I am using Firebase to send and receive messages. Once I send or receive a message, I am storing it to SQLite as follows. Now it the recent chats screen, I need the last message from all the unique chats(All the messages between a unique pair of SentTo and SentBy i.e., Mid A&B are of one unique chat) sorted by sentTime, number of unread messages in those unique chats in one single query as I am observing the SQLite database.

```
Mid(STRING)     | SentBy | SentT0 | message | readTime | sentTime| Type
----------------+--------+--------+---------+----------+---------+------
A               | AA     | JD     | M1      |   1      |    0    |  S
B               | JD     | AA     | M2      |   2      |    1    |  s
C               | AA     | JD     | M3      |   3      |    2    |  s
D               | AB     | JD     | m5      |   null   |    3    |  s
E               | AA     | JC     | M1      |   5      |    4    |  s
F               | JD     | AB     | M2      |   6      |    5    |  s
G               | AA     | JD     | M3      |   7      |    6    |  s
H               | AA     | JC     | m5      |   8      |    7    |  s
I               | AA     | JD     | M1      |   null   |    8    |  s
J               | JD     | AA     | M2      |  10      |    9    |  s
K               | AA     | JD     | M3      |  11      |    10   |  s
L               | AB     | JC     | m5      |  12      |    11   |  s
M               | AA     | JD     | M1      |  13      |    12   |  s
N               | JC     | AA     | M2      |  14      |    13   |  s
O               | AB     | JD     | M3      |  15      |    14   |  s
P               | JC     | JD     | m5      |  16      |    15   |  s
```

I've tried

```
'SELECT * , COUNT (*)from $messagesListTableName as C GROUP BY $columnSentBy , $columnSentTo '
```

This gave me the last messages and count of unique pairs but did not group them by conversation. So I got two last messages for each pair. I can group them later but I did not get the unseen message count.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe how it's not meeting your needs?

Comment: Please provide desired results.  And how do you define "unique chats".  There is no "chat id" in your data.

Comment: All the messages between a unique pair of SentTo and SentBy i.e., Mid A&B are of one unique chat

Answer (score 1):

If a unique chat is defined by the `sentBy`/`sentTo` pair (regardless of ordering), then in the most recent versions of SQLite, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by min(sentBy, sentTo), max(sentBy, sentTo) order by senttime desc) as seqnum,
             sum(case when readtime is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by min(sentBy, sentTo), max(sentBy, sentTo)) as num_unreads
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I got an SQL error at over. Looks like window functions are not supported.

Comment: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ says there is some error in the Query itself.